# Non-atomic use of check/put error during static analysis

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic

I have a code from which I am trying to get the instance of my class as I have written a wrapper around `java.util.logging.Logger`.

Below is the snippet of code in my `ClientLogger` class -

```
private static final Map<Class<?>, ClientLogger> s_classLoggers = new ConcurrentHashMap<Class<?>, ClientLogger>();

final private Logger m_logger;

private ClientLogger(final Class<?> caller) {
    m_logger = Logger.getInstance(caller);
}   

public static ClientLogger getInstance(final Class<?> klass) {
    final ClientLogger result;

    if (s_classLoggers.containsKey(klass)) {
        result = s_classLoggers.get(klass);
    } else {
        result = new ClientLogger(klass);
        s_classLoggers.put(klass, result);
    }

    return result;
}
```

And this is the way I am initializing it in my other classes where I need to use my above logger -

```
private static final ClientLogger s_logger = ClientLogger.getInstance(TestLogger.class);
```

Now when I am running my static analysis tool, it is complaining as -

```
Non-atomic use of check/put on this line s_classLoggers.put(klass, result);
```

in my `ClientLogger` class and I am not sure why? Is there anything wrong I am doing here?

**UPDATE:-**

Here is my updated code -

```
private static final ConcurrentHashMap<Class<?>, ClientLogger> s_classLoggers = new ConcurrentHashMap<Class<?>, ClientLogger>();

public static ClientLogger getInstance(final Class<?> klass) {
    final ClientLogger result;

    result = new ClientLogger(klass);
    s_classLoggers.putIfAbsent(klass, result);

    return result;
}
```

**Another Update:-**

```
private static final ConcurrentHashMap<Class<?>, ClientLogger> s_classLoggers = new ConcurrentHashMap<Class<?>, ClientLogger>();

public static ClientLogger getInstance(final Class<?> klass) {
    ClientLogger result;

    result = s_classLoggers.putIfAbsent(klass, new ClientLogger(klass));
    if (result == null) {
        result = new ClientLogger(klass);
    }       

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not thread-safe, because a different thread might call `put()` between your two calls on the first thread.

Instead, you should call `putIfAbsent()`.

Comment: Since java 8 or change the declared type of the field to `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: I don't see `putIfAbsent()` for `s_classLoggers` map. Not sure why? And I am using `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap`

Comment: @user2809564: You need to change the type of the field to `ConcurrentHashMap<T>`.

Comment: @SLaks I didn't understand. Can you edit your answer so that I can get the idea what do you mean? You mean to say generics?

Comment: @user2809564 Your `s_classLoggers` field is of type `Map`. Change it to be of type `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis got it. I have updated my question with the latest code. Can you take a look that's what you meant?

Comment: @SLaks  I have updated my question with the latest code. Can you take a look that's what you meant? And I got everything right?

Comment: @SLaks What it should be then? And what I am missing?

Comment: @SLaks are you around?

Comment: @user2809564: You need to use the return value from `putIfAbsent()` if it was already in the map, or the new value if it wasn't.

Comment: @SLaks got it. I updated my question again. Let me know this is what you meant? And also for this solution, I need to remove final modifier of result.

Comment: That's still wrong.  If you don't understand how to write this code correctly, you are not competent enough to write thread-safe code.  You need to understand what `putIfAbsent()` does.

Answer (score 1):

you are testing

```
s_classLoggers.containsKey(klass)
```

on one line of the code.  Several lines later you put in a value

```
s_classLoggers.put(klass, result);
```

Of course, another thread might have updated the hash map in the mean time.   In multithreading, you can not test on one line, and then conditionally operate on another line, because the condition might be false.  In the same way, the `get` a line later might return null because another thread might have removed the entry that was there a line before.

An atomic operation, where the test and update is done in a single operation:

```
newLogger = new ClientLogger(klass);
result = s_classLoggers.putIfAbsent(klass, newLogger);
if (result == null) {
    result = newLogger;
}
```

(changed the code above so that result is always whatever value that is mapped because putIfAbsent returns null if nothing was mapped before, and in that case the newLogger is put into the map.)

Comment: I don't see `putIfAbsent()` for `s_classLoggers` map. Not sure why? And I am using `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap`

Comment: here is the doc link:     
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#putIfAbsent%28K,%20V%29

Comment: `result = s_classLoggers.putIfAbsent(klass, new ClientLogger(klass));` This will return null for the first time call. Right? And then NPE exception will be thrown in my code.